# what happens when mq_send is called on a PEND+S task?

Tags: vxworks

In Vxworks OS what will happen if we call a mq_send function to send a message to the destination task which is already in Pended+suspended state ?

Will it block on mq_send , say property of the msq_queue is set as BLOCKING.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the message will be added to the message queue buffer until the destination task comes and picks up the message. The messages will keep on adding to the message queue until it becomes full Once the message queue is full then the sending task will be blocked based on the option which has been set for the Message queue.